# May I use Django email verification login in django-version-1.9.2?

Tags: python, django

I am using django version 1.9.2. now I want to create an two step verification login in 
First step, entering password as usual. 
Then, a randomized code will be sent to user's email address and an input displays for entering code.
After correctly entering the code, a checkbox option to "Trust this Device" displays. Upon selecting, the Computer's IP address is saved and the user can login skipping the code. Otherwise, the code step should still be required.

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you can. It can be made using Django middleware [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/)

Comment: I think this application can work as your requirement https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: yes I implemented. Thanks for comment.